# What is the meaning of "works" in Hebrews 4:10?

Tags: hebrews, sabbath

Hebrews 4:8-11 (NIV)

> 8 For if Joshua had given them rest, God would not have spoken later about another day. 9 There remains, then, a Sabbath-rest for the people of God; 10 for anyone who enters God’s rest also rests from their **works**, just as God did from his. 11 Let us, therefore, make every effort to enter that rest, so that no one will perish by following their example of disobedience.

Verse 10 says that anyone will rest of their "**works**" when they enter God's rest. What is the meaning of "**works**" in this context?

Comment: Great idea to shift the bounty to the other question :D

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator for the bounty in the other question, what improvement do you need beyond the existing answer?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - I just want to attract more peer-review to that question, that's all (context: I'm simultaneously debating seventh day Sabbatarians on another site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operative word here in Heb 4:10 is ἔργον (ergon) usually translated, "work" or "deed" etc.  In NT times, we find this word used significantly:

- Rom 3:20 - Therefore no one will be declared righteous in God's sight by the works of the law; rather, through the law we become conscious of our sin
- Rom 3:28 - For we maintain that a person is justified by faith apart from the works of the law
- Gal 2:16 - know that a person is not justified by the works of the law, but by faith
  in Jesus Christ.
- Gal 3:10 - For all who rely on the works of the law are under a curse
- Gal 3:12 - But the law is not based on faith, but the one who does the works of the law will live by them.
- Eph 2:8-10 - For it is by grace you have been saved through faith, and this not from yourselves; it is the gift of God, not by works, so that no one can boast. For we are God’s workmanship, created in Christ Jesus to do good works, which God prepared in advance as our way of life.

Thus, we have Christ's free gift of salvation frees us from having to earn that salvation by very tiring works of the law - we can rest in Christ and do "His works" as explained by the Lord Himself in Matt 11:28-30 -

> "Come to Me, all you who are weary and burdened, and I will give you
> rest. Take My yoke upon you and learn from Me; for I am gentle and
> humble in heart, and you will find rest for your souls. For My yoke is
> easy and My burden is light.”